# How to change value when passing marker with certain comment

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

I wanted to change one value when marker with certain comment starts. I've tried something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
if (marker.comment("R1 L1").time > time){
  value = 40;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check [how expressions work](https://helpx.adobe.com/au/after-effects/user-guide.html/au/after-effects/using/expression-basics.ug.html). An expression sets the value of a property with the first line that returns a value. So for example an expression could just be:

```
40
```

since that line returns the value 40. The second line in your expression `value = 40` does not return a value, it attempts to set the [`value` property](https://ae-expressions.docsforadobe.dev/property.html#value) to 40, which doesn't work, because `value` is read-only.

What you need to do is return `40` if the time is after the marker, and if not return the current `value`, thus:

```
if (marker.comment("R1 L1").time > time){
  40;
} else {
  value;
}
```

Or more tersely, using [ternary](https://codeburst.io/javascript-the-conditional-ternary-operator-explained-cac7218beeff) notation, which uses the form `(condition)? <value if true> : <value if false>`, thus:

```
(marker.comment("R1 L1").time > time)? 40 : value
```

Comment: “marker.comment” doesn't work, but “marker.key” does.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that experienced with expression, so maybe I'm understanding something wrong, but both your code and the code of @stib's answer give me clear error messages. `marker.comment` is not a function and above that, the code has several more issues.

Using part of the code from [this reference](https://ae-expressions.docsforadobe.dev/examples.html?highlight=marker#animate-scale-at-each-layer-marker) I got the following working:

```
n = 0;
t = 0;
if (marker.numKeys > 0)
{
     n = marker.nearestKey(time).index;
     if (marker.key(n).time > time)
        n--;
}
if (n > 0 )
    t = time - marker.key(n).time;

if(t>0 && marker.key(n).comment=="R1 L1")
    40;
else
    value;
```

I've created a simple shape and applied the expression for example to the opacity property (100% at start) and added a marker with the comment "R1 L1" and as soon as the playhead passes this marker the opacity changes to 40%. I think this behaves as intended.